# How to register multiple (different) redis connection pools in IOC

Tags: servicestack

I have to connect to different Redis instances from one service (we have one redis instance per database because they require different storage policies).

For each Redis DB I have several (different) repositories that take the corresponding `PooledRedisClientManager` instance in the constructor. I do not understand how to correctly register them, since they all **implement the same interface** (`IRedisClientsManager`).

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseAConnectionString));
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseBConnectionString));
```

The registrations above only differ by the connection string and I do not know how to distinguish (resolve) them. I should register something like this:

```
//Pools for database A and B
var databaseAPool = new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseAConnectionString)
var databaseBPool = new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseBConnectionString)
//Repositories for database A
container.Register(c => new AClass1Repository(databaseAPool);
container.Register(c => new AClass2Repository(databaseAPool);
// etc
//Repositories for database B
container.Register(c => new BClass1Repository(databaseBPool);
container.Register(c => new BClass2Repository(databaseBPool);
// etc
```

In my services I like to do something like:

```
//...
var AClass1Repo = ServiceStackHost.Instance.Resolve<AClass1Repository>();
var BClass2Repo = ServiceStackHost.Instance.Resolve<BClass2Repository>();

var xyz = AClass1Repo.GetSomeData(....);
BClass2Repo.StoreSomeData(somePocoInstance);
//....
```

How do I have to wire up my different Redis Connection Pools and my repositories for each database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only register 1 `IRedisClientsManager` so you wont be able to register 2 PooledRedisClientManager instances in the IOC. You can register different classes passing in different Redis Managers, but I'd also have their singleton instances defined on my AppHost so they're accessible separately when needed, e.g:

```
public class AppHost
{
    PooledRedisClientManager RedisManagerA { get; set; }
    PooledRedisClientManager RedisManagerB { get; set; }

    public void Configure(Container container)
    {
        RedisManagerA = new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseAConnString);
        RedisManagerB = new PooledRedisClientManager(databaseBConnString);

        container.Register(c => new AClass1Repository(RedisManagerA);
        container.Register(c => new AClass2Repository(RedisManagerA);

        container.Register(c => new BClass1Repository(RedisManagerB);
        container.Register(c => new BClass2Repository(RedisManagerB);
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't need to access the `ServiceStackHost` from inside your Services, you can just declare them as dependencies and they'll be injected, e.g:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public AClass1Repository ARepo1 { get; set; }
    public BClass1Repository BRepo1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. One more question regarding Redis based `ICacheClient`: 
PooledRedisClientManager RedisCache {get;set;}
RedisCachePool = new PooledRedisClientManager(cacheDbConnString);
container.Register(c=> new WHAT CLASS HERE(RedisCachePool); ??
Regarding `ServiceStackHost`: thanks for the hint, works fine for all classes derived from `Service`. Does NOT work in my own AuthenticationProvider implementation.

Comment: If you want to use Redis for your Cache Client you need to choose which Redis Pool you want to use for your cache, e.g `container.Register(c => RedisManagerA.GetCacheClient());`. The preferred API to access dependencies that aren't injected is either `HostContext.TryResolve<T>()` or if you have access to `IRequest` you can use `IRequest.TryResolve<T>()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize that `GetCacheClient()` is a method of `PooledRedisClientManager`!